# pread in C #define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500

Tags: c, compilation, header-files

I'm having some trouble getting pread() to work in a header file.  Every time I compile the program, it tells me that I  have an because of the statement `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500`.  The error is:

```
In file included from networking.h:6,
                 from networking.c:1:
/usr/include/bsd/stdlib.h:47: error: expected ‘)’ before ‘*’ token
make: *** [all] Error 1
```

The headers in the header file is

```
#ifndef NETWORKING_H
#define NETWORKING_H

#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500

#include<bsd/stdlib.h>
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<sys/errno.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<sys/socket.h>

#include<ctype.h>
#include<fcntl.h>
#include<limits.h>
#include<netdb.h>
#include<pwd.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<unistd.h>

#include"html.h"
```

Thanks!

```
#ifndef LIBBSD_STDLIB_H
#define LIBBSD_STDLIB_H

#include <sys/cdefs.h>
#include <sys/stat.h>
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

/* For compatibility with NetBSD, which defines humanize_number here. */
#include <libutil.h>

/* FIXME: Temporary inclusions to avoid API breakage, will be removed soon. */
#include <bsd/stdio.h>
#include <bsd/unistd.h>

__BEGIN_DECLS
u_int32_t arc4random();
void arc4random_stir();
void arc4random_addrandom(u_char *dat, int datlen);

int dehumanize_number(const char *str, int64_t *size);

char *getprogname ();
void setprogname (char *);
```

Comment: What does stdlib.h:47 look like? (And a line or two above and below it)

Comment: What makes you think the error is with the `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500` line? That's line 4, the error is on line 47 (unless there are 43 lines before the ones you quoted).

Comment: @BenjiWiebe it shouldn't matter what file looks like because it is a system include file right?

Comment: @Barmar if I comment out the line `#define _XOPEN_SOURCE 500` it works except for recognizing the pread() function.

Comment: @tpar44 It shouldn't, no. But the people who created the system headers are humans, and humans are capable of making mistakes. Yes, I am human too, and maybe I made a mistake and it really *doesn't* matter.

Comment: @tpar44 That doesn't mean the error is caused by that line. That line is used to tell other include files which declarations they should create, so removing it changes what those other files do. The problem is in one of the places that's dependent on that macro (e.g. line 47 of the file).

Comment: @Barmar I edited the file with the appropriate header file

Comment: @tpar44 Not sure if it's the only issue, but you're missing a semicolon on the `void setprogname (char *)` line...

Comment: @twalberg nah, thats my fault, I actually didn't copy it from the file. sorry about that

Comment: There are no line numbers, so how are we supposed to know which is line 47?

Comment: @Barmar sorry line 47 is `void arc4random_addrandom(u_char *dat, int datlen);`

Comment: Is `u_char` defined somewhere prior?

Comment: I'll bet you have `#define u_char ...` somewhere in your program, and it's conflicting with the standard typedef.

Comment: I do not have u_char defined anywhere else...

Comment: `u_char` is nonstandard. Defining `_XOPEN_SOURCE` will inhibit nonstandard crap from getting defined in the system headers. Best solution would be `s/u_char/unsigned char/g` on this broken source.

Comment: @R.. are you saying that I can't use _XOPEN_SOURCE directive with bsd/stdlib.h?

Comment: I'm saying that libbsd seems to be badly non-portable and incompatible with building in a standards-conformant environment which is what you get by defining `_XOPEN_SOURCE` or `_POSIX_C_SOURCE`. You should report this issue upstream.

Comment: @R Defining `_XOPEN_SOURCE` doesn't "inhibit" anything. It just makes the [XSI](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap02.html#tag_02_01_04) declarations visible in the headers.